# Python does not open default web browser to show visualization results in pyvis?

Tags: python, pyvis

In one part of my code, I need to visualize the generate graph using pyvis library. When i was using python 3.10 everything was ok and the graph was visualized in the default browser, but now due to some reasons i need to use python 3.6.4. In this situation when i generate graph and i want to open it in default browser (which is firefox now), it always opens Internet Explorer of windows and does not show anything and it always go to bing!, whereas my default browser is FireFox. Is there anything wrong with python 3.6.4? the code below is used to visualize. How can i open the generated graph in the default browser? I really appreciate answers which solves my problem.

```
palette = (sns.color_palette("Pastel1", n_colors=len(set(labelList.values()))))  
        palette = palette.as_hex()
        colorDict = {}
        counter = 0
        for i in palette:
            colorDict[counter] = i
            counter += 1

     

        N = Network(height='100%', width='100%', directed=False, notebook=False, heading = self.headerName)
        for n in G.nodes:

            N.add_node(n, color=(colorDict[labelList[n]]), size=5)
        for e in G.edges.data():
            N.add_edge(e[0], e[1])


        N.show('./result.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well. Now I simply insert the ".show()" method in a try-except block, and click each time on the html file generated to visualize it in Chrome (annoying, I know).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `notebook=False` when calling the `graph.show()`.

```
N.show('./result.html', notebook=False)
```

It seems in the `pyvis version=0.3`, the `graph.show()` has its out `notebook` parameter overriding the `Network()`